# disabled block in BEM

Tags: css, bem

I'm using BEM and I would like to know how to "disable" a block (`.element`).
By disable I mean using a different CSS background to emulate a disabled state.

```
.element {
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.element__title {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" class="element">
    <div class="element__title">this is the title</div>
</div>
```

Should I create

```
.element--disabled {
    background-color: #EEE;
}
```

and apply that to

```
<div id="test" class="element element--disabled">
```

What about the `__title`? I'm not sure if my approach is correct because I want to overwrite the entire block.

Comment: **"Best Way"** questions are either too broad, **opinion based** or require discussion and so are off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: understood. Just updated the question. hope that clarifies what I need to do. thank you

Answer (score 2):

`element--disabled` will be just fine. For more info see https://en.bem.info/method/naming-convention/#modifier-name